# Pro-guard - error while parsing

Tags: android, android-proguard

My app is using zendesk sdk as well zendesk chat sdk. I am using the pro-guard configuaraion provided by SDK. Below is the error while using pro-guard configuration

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForProductionRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain$ToolchainException: Jack configuration exception.
>     Error while parsing '/home/mangesh/.android/build-cache/15c44a5d9c68798ae18de800a572685f9f74a9f2/output/proguard.txt':2

Below is the error line in above mentioned file

-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.zopim.android.sdk.** { *; }

I am using jack option for my project. I tried to find above mentioned pro-guard configuration line. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Did you go through the documentation page of zendesk proguard "httpshttps://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android/use_proguard", It's clearly written how to use

Comment: Yes. I am using same pro-guard rules. I tried even there sample app with pro-guard config provided on github. Only difference which I can see is I am using jack option while there are not.

Comment: I heard this somewhere but was not sure of it.Thanks for bringing to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with zendesksdk. Currently there SDK does not support jack option. More information at https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115001255048-zendesk-sdk-compatibility-issue-with-jack-option#